# Gmaps4rails - Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm trying to figure out how to get a map to display the address a user creates.

I have an address model and a projects model.

The associations are:

Address:

```
 belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
```

Project:

```
has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

In address.rb, I have:

```
def full_project_address_formal
    [self.first_line, middle_line, last_line, country_name].compact.join("<br>").html_safe
  end
```

I also then have:

```
def first_line
    [unit, street_number, street.titlecase].join(' ')
  end

  def middle_line
    if self.building.present? 
    end
  end

  def last_line
    [city.titlecase, region.titlecase, zip].join('   ')
  end

  def country_name
    country = self.country
    ISO3166::Country[country]
  end
```

In my show page, I then have:

```
<%= @project.addresses.first.project_address %>
```

All of that works to display the project address.

I then want to display a map.

I have installed these gems:

```
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'underscore-rails'
gem 'countries'
gem 'country_select'
```

In my application.js, I have:

```
//= require gmap3.min
//= require underscore
```

In my address.rb, I have:

```
geocoded_by :full_project_address_formal   # can also be an IP address
after_validation :geocode
```

In my address controller I have (I don't know why - I copied it from another post on SO - although my address model does have latitude and longitude in the schema):

```
def index
  @addresses = Address.all
  authorize @addresses

  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@addresses) do |address, marker|
    marker.lat address.latitude
    marker.lng address.longitude
    end
  end
```

I'm completely lost for what to do next. I've tried at least 30 different ways of trying to display the address in a map.

```
<strong>PROJECT HQ</strong>
                                <ul class="map-list medium-text">
                                    <%= @project.addresses.first.project_address %>
                                    <!-- <li><span data-icon="&#xe01e;"></span>mail@develpixel.com</li> -->
                                </ul>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="two-cols-column">
                            <div id="map">

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

In my main.js file, I have:

```
if (dp.fn.gmap3) {
        var target_map = dp('#map');
        var lat = target_map.data('lat');
        var lng = target_map.data('lng');
        target_map.gmap3({
                marker: {
                latLng: [lat, lng],
                draggable: false
            },
                map: {
                      options: {
                            zoom: 12,
                    scrollwheel: false,
                    disableDefaultUI: true,
                    styles:
                            [{"featureType": "landscape.man_made", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"color": "#f7f1df"}]}, {"featureType": "landscape.natural", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"color": "#d0e3b4"}]}, {"featureType": "landscape.natural.terrain", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}, {"featureType": "poi", "elementType": "labels", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}, {"featureType": "poi.business", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}, {"featureType": "poi.medical", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"color": "#fbd3da"}]}, {"featureType": "poi.park", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"color": "#bde6ab"}]}, {"featureType": "road", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}, {"featureType": "road", "elementType": "labels", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}, {"featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [{"color": "#ffe15f"}]}, {"featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [{"color": "#efd151"}]}, {"featureType": "road.arterial", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [{"color": "#ffffff"}]}, {"featureType": "road.local", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [{"color": "black"}]}, {"featureType": "transit.station.airport", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [{"color": "#cfb2db"}]}, {"featureType": "water", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"color": "#a2daf2"}]}]
                      }
                }

          });
    }
```

I"m lost and stuck. Does anyone know how to get from where I am to the point where I can take an address and produce a map in my show?

A SECOND ATTEMPT. HAVING WATCHED THIS YOU TUBE VIDEO: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0l-7en3dUw&feature=youtu.be

I'm still stuck, but not sure how to approach solving this problem.  My complete address setup is now:

gems:

```
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'underscore-rails'
gem 'countries'
gem 'country_select'
```

application.js

```
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
```

vendor/assets/javascript/ underscore.js

I copied and pasted the entire underscore production version. In the video, that appears to be 1 uncommented line. I couldn't find that. Instead, I have a long page of gibberish.

address model:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base


  geocoded_by :full_address   # can also be an IP address
  before_save :capitalise_address
  before_save :upcase_zip
  # --------------- associations

    belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true

  # --------------- scopes

  # --------------- validations
    validates_presence_of :street_number, :street, :zip, :country 


  # --------------- class methods

  def first_line
    [unit, street_number, street.titlecase].join(' ')
  end

  def middle_line
    if self.building.present? 
    end
  end

  def last_line
    [city.titlecase, region.titlecase, zip].join('   ')
  end


  def country_name
    country = self.country
    ISO3166::Country[country]
  end


  def full_address
    [self.first_line, middle_line, last_line, country_name].compact.join("<br>").html_safe
  end


  after_validation :geocode#, if  self.full_address.changed? 


end
```

address controller:

```
def index
  @addresses = Address.all
  authorize @addresses

  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@addresses) do |address, marker|
    marker.lat address.latitude
    marker.lng address.longitude
    end
  end
```

I don't know why this is in an index action. I"m trying to use a projects/show action. I've not understood the reasons for the above step.

projects show:

```
<div id="map">
    <%= render partial: "address" %>
</div>
```

views/projects/_address.html.erb

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.18&sensor=false&client=&key=&libraries=geometry&language=&hl=&region="></script> 
<script src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/src/infobox_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script> <!-- only if you need custom infoboxes -->
```

Not sure if this file is supposed to have any html in it. following this tutorial (
https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails), I've no clue as to how the maps (even if it is working, would know what address to use.

app/assets/javascripts/addresses.js

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

not sure if Im supposed to put the above inside script tags

I'm lost. At this point, I have an error that says:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError at /projects/26
SyntaxError: [stdin]:13:32: unexpected <
```

I don't know where to look for the error because I don't know what anything is supposed to look like. I'm lost and stuck.  I have read the google api documentation (it assumes knowledge of js at a level that I don't have) and all of the geocoder and gmaps4rails wiki documentation.

A THIRD ATTEMPT

I found this wiki resource, which gives template js and html. http://apneadiving.github.io

I replace the content of my addresses.js file with:

```
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'geolocation'} }, function(){
  if(navigator.geolocation)
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayOnMap);
});

function displayOnMap(position){
  var marker = handler.addMarker({
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
  });
  handler.map.centerOn(marker);
};
```

And add make the content of my partial:

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.18&sensor=false&client=&key=&libraries=geometry&language=&hl=&region="></script> 
<script src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/src/infobox_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script> <!-- only if you need custom infoboxes -->


    <div style='width: 800px;'>
        <div id="geolocation" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
    </div>
```

I get an error that says:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError at /projects/26
SyntaxError: [stdin]:2:1: reserved word 'var'
```

Thanks to Max below, for the help with removing the '.coffee' extension from my js files. Now, there is just a blank space where the map was supposed to be.

Comment: Start with the [google maps api guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Audience). `gmaps4rails` gives you just enough to get going but its not a replacement for actually knowing what you are doing. You also need to configure your model to actually geocode a lat/lng from the address fields. You should really read the [geocoder readme](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) - this is not something that you can just copypaste.

Comment: Thank you for these comments. Having re-read the geocoder documents - I can't find a single error in what I have established to this point. If you can see something that I have done wrong (that gave you cause to make that comment), I'd really appreciate your help in identifying the problem. Having re-read the google maps api guide, watched the you tube (silent) tutorial and struggled through at least 20 other video resources, I"m still getting errors. I really don't understand why people bother to make comments of the nature you just have. They are most certainly not helpful.

Comment: You are using javascript in a coffeescript file. Coffescript is not a superset (unlike Sass). Change the extension to .js

Comment: You can try this tutorial - http://www.openmindedinnovations.com/blogs/leaflet-and-ruby-on-rails-with-google-tiles. It helped me to configure my models with maps and display it properly. Some adjustments may be needed there. If you have any issues there, you can ask me, I'll try to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to display a map on a project's show page along with the project's address/addresses.

The @hash variable (from the tutorial) contains the required information to create markers on the map (eg. latitude, longitude etc) and it is used as `markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);` which then actually adds the markers with that information.

In your case, since you need the map on project's show page, you should set @hash in show action of the ProjectsController with @addresses set to whatever addresses you want to display on the page - presumably @project.addresses, where @project value is set before @addressses.

I think your lat & lng are stored not in fields/columns named lat & lng but latitude & longitude in which case you need to mention them specifically like this -  `geocoded_by :full_project_address_formal, latitude: :lat, longitude: :lng`. You should make sure that the values of latitude & longitude fields are indeed present for the addresses in the database to be safe.

```
def show
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @addresses = @project.addresses

  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@addresses) do |address, marker|
    marker.lat address.latitude
    marker.lng address.longitude
    marker.infowindow address.full_project_address_formal
  end
end
```

Once you set the value of @hash in ProjectsController's show action, you can access it inside a script tag in projects/show view. To start with, you can keep the show view simple as this.

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.18&sensor=false&client=&key=&libraries=geometry&language=&hl=&region="></script> 
<script src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/src/infobox_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script> <!-- only if you need custom infoboxes -->

<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>

<script>
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps. If you get stuck somewhere or need assistance, let me know.